# Using Cython to wrap a C++ class that uses OpenCV types as parameters

Tags: c++, python, opencv, cython

I'm trying to use Cython to wrap a C++ class that uses some OpenCV types as parameters, then I intend to use this wrapped class from Python. A simplified version of the C++ class looks like:

"transform.h"

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

namespace geom
{
    class Transform
    {
    public:
        Transform(cv::Vec3d &euler, cv::Vec3d &t);
        void set_euler(cv::Vec3d &euler);
        cv::Vec3d get_euler();
    }
}
```

Vec3d is defined in OpenCV as:

```
template<typename _Tp, int n> class Vec : public Matx<_Tp, n, 1> {...};
typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;
```

and Matx is defined as:

```
template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> class Matx {...};
```

My first attempt to the cython wrapper looks like this:

"geom_gateway.pyx"

```
cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Matx[_Tp, int m, int n]:
        Matx()
        Matx(_Tp v0, _Tp v1, _Tp v2)

cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Vec[_Tp, int n](Matx[_Tp, n, 1]): 
        Vec()
        Vec(_Tp v0, _Tp v1, _Tp v2)

ctypedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d

cdef extern from "transform.h" namespace "geom":
    cdef cppclass Transform:
        Transform(cv::Vec3d &euler, cv::Vec3d &t)
        void set_euler(cv::Vec3d &euler)
        cv::Vec3d get_euler()
```

This wrapper is unfinished but I just wanted to build it and check that I get the syntax right. 
Unfortunately, when I build it I don't get too far, I get:

```
cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Matx[_Tp, int m, int n]:
                                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

../basics/geom_gateway:3:29: Expected ']', found 'm'
```

what's wrong? I imagine that it's possible to have multiple value templates in Cython? 
otherwise how could I wrap in Cython a C++ class that uses these templated types from OpenCV?
I suspect I may have other problems in this piece of code, please feel free to point out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution!  based on this thread:

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/cython-users/136v44ees2/wrap-c-template-function-with-multiple-template-parameter-and-typdef-for-specific-instantiations-of-the-typdef

Instead of declaring the templates in cython I can declare a specific case in C++ in quotes and then name my cython variable with that. For Vec3d would be:

```
cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Vec3d "cv::Vec<double, 3>": 
        Vec3d()
        Vec3d(double v0, double v1, double v2)
```

Note that the namespace "cv" has to be within the quotations or it won't work.
and for the Matx33d

```
cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Matx33d "cv::Matx<double, 3, 3>":
        Matx33d()
        Matx33d(double v0, double v1, double v2, double v3, double v4, double v5, double v6, double v7, double v8)
```