# Cython C++ wrapper operator() overloading error

Tags: c++, python, opencv, cython

Connected with my previous question. 
[Using Cython to wrap a C++ class that uses OpenCV types as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676860/using-cython-to-wrap-a-c-class-that-uses-opencv-types-as-parameters)

Now I'm stuck in another error. My cython wrapping code of the OpenCV type Matx33d looks like:

```
cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Matx33d "cv::Matx<double, 3, 3>":
        Matx33d()
        Matx33d(double v0, double v1, double v2, double v3, double v4, double v5, double v6, double v7, double v8)
        double& operator()(int i, int j)
```

Then I define a function to copy the Matx33d to a numpy array.

```
cdef Matx33d2numpy(Matx33d &m):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] np_m = np.empty((3,3), dtype=np.float64)  
    np_m[0,0]= m(0,0); np_m[0,1]= m(0,1); np_m[0,2]= m(0,2)
    np_m[1,0]= m(1,0); np_m[1,1]= m(1,1); np_m[1,2]= m(1,2)
    np_m[2,0]= m(2,0); np_m[2,1]= m(2,1); np_m[2,2]= m(2,2)    
    return np_m
```

When I compile the cython wrapper I get these error

```
geom_gateway.cpp(2528) error C3861: '()': identifier not found
```

This corresponds to the first use of Matx33d::operator(), that's when accessing m(0,0) in the code above.
If I look at the generated geom_gateway.cpp line 2528 I get:

```
  *__Pyx_BufPtrStrided2d(__pyx_t_5numpy_double_t *, __pyx_pybuffernd_np_m.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_6, __pyx_pybuffernd_np_m.diminfo[0].strides, __pyx_t_7, __pyx_pybuffernd_np_m.diminfo[1].strides) = operator()(0, 0);
```

I don't understand this operator()(0, 0) there alone at the end of the line without any object!! How is this possible? Is this a Cython bug? or is the syntax I'm using for the operator() wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is an object, it's `m` and it's passed as an argument.

Comment: sorry, I can't see the m passed as a parameter in the line I copied from geom_gateway.cpp (line 2528). Could you point it out? I don't know much about the python C API

Comment: `cdef Matx33d2numpy(Matx33d &m):` <== it's a `Matx33d` passed by reference as `m`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. The problem is that I get a compiler error, and when I look at the line of the error in the cpp file that cython generates I don't see the "m", I see the line I pasted which looks like "some very long Python C API expression that I don't understand" =  operator()(0, 0); and there is where I can't see the m anywhere, that should be m.operator()(0, 0); but there is no m!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why that error happened, to me it looks like the syntax

```
double& operator()(int i, int j)
```

...should work, but it doesn't. This syntax does work for other operators like `+`,`-`,`/`,`*`

An alternative syntax that does work is the following:

```
double& get "operator()"(int i, int j)
```

Then in cython code when we want to use the `operator()(i,j)` instead we call `get(i, j)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It helped me wrap boost/random and test it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem anymore in Cython 2.4

Comment: @BryceGuinta cython 2.4, how is it versioned? mine is 0.29, so different

Comment: i use "operator<" but it doesn't work: `cdef bool "operator<"(const HeapqItem a, const HeapqItem b)` --> `Function signature does not match previous declaration` although it's the only place