# Cython cannot use operator()

Tags: c++, numpy, cython

When I try to use the following Cython code, I get the error I posted at the end about `operator()` not being defined. It appears that when I try to use operators Cython does not interpret it as a member function (notice there is no member access in the C++ source). If I try to call `prng.operator()()` then Cython will fail translation.

Is something special needed to use operator overloading in Cython?

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "ratchet.hpp" namespace "ratchet::detail":
    cdef cppclass Ratchet:
        Ratchet()
        unsigned long get64()

cdef extern from "float.hpp" namespace "prng":
    cdef cppclass FloatPRNG[T]:
        double operator()()



cdef FloatPRNG[Ratchet] prng

def ratchet_arr(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] A):
    cdef unsigned int i
    for i in range(len(A)):
        A[i] = prng()


def ratchet_arr(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] A):
    cdef unsigned int i, j
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            A[i][j] = prng()
```

`ratchet.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_7ratchet_ratchet_arr(PyObject*, PyArrayObject*)’:
ratchet.cpp:1343:162: error: ‘operator()’ not defined
     *__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(__pyx_t_5numpy_float64_t *, __pyx_pybuffernd_A.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_3, __pyx_pybuffernd_A.diminfo[0].strides) = operator()();`

Some more information inspired by Ianh. It appears that `operator()` cannot be used when the object is stack allocated

```
cat thing.pyx
cdef extern from 'thing.hpp':
    cdef cppclass Thing:
        Thing(int)
        Thing()
        int operator()()

# When this function doesn't exist, thing.so compiles fine
cpdef ff():
    cdef Thing t
    return t()

cpdef gg(x=None):
    cdef Thing* t
    if x:
        t = new Thing(x)
    else:
        t = new Thing()
    try:
        return t[0]()
    finally:
        del t

cat thing.hpp
#pragma once

class Thing {
    int val;

    public:
    Thing(int v): val(v) {}
    Thing() : val(4) {}

    int operator()() { return val; }
};
```

Comment: nice question... it would be better to include the full error message.... are you telling Cython compiler this is a C++ application and not a C application?

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thankyou for the suggestion. I am telling Cython to generate C++ code. This error is actually from gcc. The Cython translation succeeds. gcc is right to complain here as there is no object associated with `operator()` being called. If I instead call a different member function of prng there would be a member deference in the code.

Comment: This looks like a not-yet-implemented feature. I tried putting together a simple example and it just doesn't work. There is a simple work around in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690005/cython-c-wrapper-operator-overloading-error) though. If you'd like, I can post a more full example. It is really not ideal though. This could be good to bring up on the mailing list.

Comment: Hmm. Nope, the documentation does say that operator overloading is supported now. There isn't a caveat about `operator()`. It's definitely a bug.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have spoken too soon. I still don't see the problem with your code, but I'll post a working example. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @IanH haha, bugger isn't it...thanks for sticking though it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: This should be fixed as of Cython 0.24 and later. I've left the workaround here for completeness.

---

After looking through the C++ compiler errors of examples like yours a little more, what appears to be happening is that Cython has a bug when overloading `operator()` for a stack allocated object.
It appears to be trying to call `operator()` as if it were some sort of function you had defined instead of as a method of the C++ object you have defined.
There are two possible workarounds.
You can either alias the call operator and give it a different name in Cython than in C.
You can also just allocate the object on the heap instead.

Depending on your use case, it could be a good idea to just patch the C file generated by Cython.
You'd basically just have to search for hanging calls to `operator()` change them to method calls on the proper C++ object.
I tried this with my example below and it worked, and it wasn't terribly difficult to trace which objects I needed to insert into the code.
This approach will work well if you are only trying to write Python bindings to the library and will not be making a large number of calls to `operator()` at the Cython level, but it could become an awful pain if you have a large amount of development you intend to do in Cython.

You could try bug reporting it too.
That would be good regardless of which route you take to get it working.
It seems like the sort of thing that should be easy to fix as well, but I'm not an expert on Cython's internals.

Here's a minimal working example of how to use `operator()` for a heap allocated object in Cython. It works for me on Cython 0.21.

`Thing.hpp`

```
#pragma once

class Thing{
    public:
        int val;
        Thing(int);
        int operator()(int);};
```

`Thing.cpp`

```
#include "Thing.hpp"

Thing::Thing(int val){
    this->val = val;}

int Thing::operator()(int num){
    return this->val + num;}
```

`Thing.pxd`

```
cdef extern from "Thing.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Thing:
        Thing(int val) nogil
        int operator()(int num) nogil
```

`test_thing.pyx`

```
from Thing cimport Thing

cpdef test_thing(int val, int num):
    cdef Thing* t = new Thing(val)
    print "initialized thing"
    print "called thing."
    print "value was: ", t[0](num)
    del t
    print "deleted thing"
```

`setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from os import system

# First compile an object file containing the Thing class.
system('g++ -c Thing.cpp -o Thing.o')

ext_modules = [Extension('test_thing',
                         sources=['test_thing.pyx'],
                         language='c++',
                         extra_link_args=['Thing.o'])]

# Build the extension.
setup(name = 'cname',
      packages = ['cname'],
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

After running the setup file, I start the Python interpreter in the same directory and run

```
from test_thing import test_thing
test_thing(1, 2)
```

and it prints the output

```
initialized thing
called thing.
value was:  3
deleted thing
```

showing that the operator is working properly.

Now, if you want to do this for a stack allocated object, you can change the Cython interface as follows:

`Thing.pxd`

```
cdef extern from "Thing.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Thing:
        Thing(int val) nogil
        int call "operator()"(int num) nogil
```

`test_thing.pyx`

```
from Thing cimport Thing

cpdef test_thing(int val, int num):
    cdef Thing t = Thing(val)
    print "initialized thing"
    print "called thing."
    print "value was: ", t.call(num)
    print "thing is deleted when it goes out of scope."
```

The C++ files and setup file can still be used as they are.

Comment: thanks for the example! Works on my machine too. Take a look at the information I added to my question. I think you inspired me enough to find where the difference between our code and find the issue. Maybe you could add something to your answer about stack allocated objects (if you can confirm that that is the issue) please?

Comment: @chewsocks Thanks for that comment. I went back and looked at it again. It seems to be a bug that only applies to stack allocated objects. I'm not entirely certain why. This would be a good bug to bring up on the Cython user list. People that are more familiar with Cython's core will probably be able to fix it without too much trouble.