# Set coefficient/element of Eigen::Matrix3d in Cython

Tags: cython, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to create a wrapper in Cython for a library which uses Eigen::Matrix3d matrices. How can I set an individual element/coefficient of the Matrix3d object?

I know, I can get the value with the `coeff(row, col)` method but could not find any function `set_coeff(row, col, value)` - or however that might be called - to set the value.

After declaring the Matrix3d with

```
cdef decl_eigen.Matrix3d t = decl_eigen.Matrix3d()
```

I want to set the values, but none of the following constructs work in Cython:

```
t << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
t(0,0) = 1
t[0][0] = 1
```

and I cannot use a constructor with the values, because to my knowledge there does not exist any.

Here are the files I have come up so far:

**decl_eigen.pxd**:

```
cdef extern from "Eigen/Dense" namespace "Eigen":
    cdef cppclass Vector3d:
        Matrix3d() except +
        double coeff(int row, int col)
```

**decl_foo.pxd**:

```
cimport decl_eigen

cdef extern from "../foo.hpp" namespace "MyFoo":

    cdef cppclass Bar:
        Bar() except +
        void transform(decl_eigen.Matrix3d &transformation)
```

**foo.pyx**:

```
import decl_eigen
cimport decl_foo

cdef class Bar:

    cdef decl_foo.Bar *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new decl_foo.Bar()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def transform(self, transformation):
        cdef decl_eigen.Matrix3d t = decl_eigen.Matrix3d()
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                k = i*3 + j
                # Set the coefficient of t(i,j) to transformation[k], but how????
        self.thisptr.transform(t)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have no experience with cython, so please bear with me. There is the `data()` [function](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a4663159a1450fa89214b1ab71f7ef5bf) which gives you access a pointer to the data. You could then do the math to assign the desired value. Additionally, you state that `cdef decl_eigen.Matrix3d t = decl_eigen.Matrix3d()` doesn't work, and then have `cdef decl_eigen.Matrix3d t = decl_eigen.Matrix3d()` in `foo.pyx`. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks Avi for pointing out this inconsistency. The `cdef`-declaration does work. I rephrased my question a bit.

Comment: Avi's suggestion does work with the following modifications:

Comment: @AviGinsburg 's suggestion does work with the following modifications: **decl_eigen.pxd**: Add `double * data()`. **foo.pyx** needs the following added: `cdef double *d = t.data()` and the values can be set with `d[j*3+i] = <double>transformation[k]`. I prefer @DavidW 's approach, even if it more complicate: I do not have to worry about the row and columns order of the `data`, it's done automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not as straightforward as it should be, but you can make it work.

Element access in Eigen looks to mostly be done through `operator()`:

```
// (copied from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html)
MatrixXd m(2,2);
m(0,0) = 3;
m(1,0) = 2.5;
m(0,1) = -1;
m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
```

Therefore, we need to define operator() so you can access it in Cython. I've assumed it returns a `double&` - I can't actually find the definition in Eigen since it's buried deep in a template class hierarchy (It's not terribly important what it actually returns - it acts like it returns a double&, which should be good enough).

Unfortunately, `operator()` seems slightly broken in Cython (see [Cython C++ wrapper operator() overloading error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690005/cython-c-wrapper-operator-overloading-error)) so we have to alias it as something else. I've used `element`.

```
cdef extern from "eigen3/Eigen/Dense" namespace "Eigen":
    # I'm also unsure if you want a Matrix3d or a Vector3d
    # so I assumed matrix
    cdef cppclass Matrix3d:
        Matrix3d() except +
        double& element "operator()"(int row,int col)
```

In principle we'd just like to be able to do `m.element(0,0) = 5`. However, Cython doesn't like this. Therefore, I've had to create a function which does this through a slightly complicated assignment to pointer type mechanism.

```
cdef void set_matrix_element(Matrix3d& m, int row, int col, double elm):
    cdef double* d = &(m.element(row,col))
    d[0] = elm
```

Therefore, to set a matrix element, we just call this function. Here's the function I made to test it on:

```
def get_numbers():
    cdef Matrix3d m = Matrix3d()
    cdef int i
    for i in range(3):
        set_matrix_element(m,i,i,i)
    return m.element(0,0),m.element(1,1),m.element(2,2),m.element(1,2)
    # returns 0,1,2, and something else (I get 0, but in principle 
    # I think it's undefined since it's never been specifically set)
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidW for sharing your insight and lengthy, but easy to follow, explanation!!